# Shell script: Remove hello world docker container without knowing ID

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, docker

I'm running `hello world` docker container in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker run hello-world
```

I'm doing this to verify if the installation of docker was correct. After this I would like to remove this container again. But as I don't know the ID of this new container I can't remove it:

```
sudo docker rm hello-world
```

... is failing.

Comment: if you wish delete container after quit, use --rm option, like  docker run -ti --rm alpine sh,  the container will auto delete after you exit the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the container a name:

```
sudo docker run --name hello-world-container hello-world
```

Then you can remove it by name:

```
sudo docker rm hello-world-container
```

Answer (score 17):

In the docs of docker: [Explore the Application](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application) it's described how you can do this.

When you `docker run hello-world`, the container gets created with a random name that you can check with the following command:

```
docker container ls --all
```

Under the `NAMES` column of the output of the command you can check the generated name (you can see below on my example image. peaceful_morse in my case).

Then you can use this name as a parameter when you call the docker remove command:

```
docker rm peaceful_morse
```

Image with all the steps:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`--filter`](https://docs.docker.com/config/filter/) to select the image(s) you want, and [`--format`](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/) to specify an output format suitable for `docker rm` (though of course in this case the `-q` option is a convenient shorthand for `--format '{{.ID}}'`).

```
docker ps --filter 'ancestor=hello-world' -q |
xargs docker rm
```

If the image is still running, you need to stop it first, or add the `-f` option to `docker rm`.

(In case it's not obvious, `xargs` reads the input from the pipe, and moves the strings it reads to the end of the command line, then executes it.)

This is somewhat error-prone (you might end up killing more than you wanted to if there is more than one matching image); you are much better off if you provide a `--name` when you initially `run` the container.

Answer (score -1):

docker rm 187593128c2a

187593128c2a(This is contaniner id you will get  whenyou will run docker ps -all)